# Executar o comando TOP no exec em C - Linux?

Tags: c, linux

Codigo atualizado ,ele nao executa os comandos

```
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <unistd.h> 
#include <stdio.h>  



void ExeclLS(int argc, char **argv)  {
    char *args[] = {"ls", "-aF", "/", 0};
    char *env[] = { 0 };

    printf("Rodando o bin/ls\n");
    execve("bin/ls", args, env);
}

void ExeclTop(int argc, char **argv) {
    char *args[] = {"top", "-aF", "/", 0};
    char *env[] = { 0 };

    printf("Rodando o bin/top\n");
    execve("/usr/bin/top", args, env);
}

int main() {

    int valorMenu;

    printf("Digite o comando : 1 - ls , 2-top\n");
    scanf("%i",&valorMenu);

    if (valorMenu == 1){
    printf("Rodando o bin/ls\n");
    ExeclLS(0, NULL);

    }else{
    printf("Rodando o bin/Top\n");
    ExeclTop(0,NULL);

    }

        perror("execve");   
        exit(1);
    return 0;
 }
```

Alguem pode me ajudar?

Comment: O `perror()` dá alguma mensagem de erro interessante?

Comment: Esse código executa normalmente,mas quando eu coloco "/bin/top" ele imprime "execve" e depois nenhum arquivo encontrado

Comment: Então ... isso quer dizer que o "top" não está na directoria "/bin". Faz `whereis top` para tentar descobrir onde ele está.

Comment: Obrigada! Me ajudou muito

Comment: A tua estrutura de `if` / `if` / `else` não está bem organizada. O `else` apenas diz respeito ao segundo `if`.

Comment: Atualizei o codigo la

Comment: falta `/` em `execve("bin/ls", args, env);` ==> `execve("/bin/ls", args, env);`

Answer (score 3):

No *snippet*

```
    if (valorMenu == 1) {
        printf("Rodando o bin/ls\n");
        void ExeclLS(int argc, char **argv);    // <== ATENÇÃO
    }
```

a linha com a chamada de atenção "não faz nada". Ela é apenas uma declaração.

Para executares a função escreve, por exemplo

```
        ExeclLS(0, NULL);
```

Comment: Coloquei o argumento e nada :/
"Rodando o bin/ls
Rodando o bin/top
Nenhum comando encontrado
execve: No such file or directory"

Answer (score 2):

A mensagem do `perror()`

> /bin/top: nenhum arquivo encontrado

indica que o `top` não está na directoria `/bin`.
Na linha de comandos, faz `whereis top` para tentar descobrir onde está o programa em questão.

```
$ whereis top
top: /usr/bin/top
```

Neste caso o `top` está na directoria `/usr/bin`.